# How to get maximum and minimum values of a range factor in R?

Tags: r

Hi I'm new to R and I cannot figure how to do the following:

I have the output of the cut function which seems to be ranges of type factor

```
 [1] (1.1e+05,1.74e+05] (1.1e+05,1.74e+05] [3.09e+04,6e+04]   (1.74e+05,2.4e+05]
 [5] (1.74e+05,2.4e+05] (1.1e+05,1.74e+05] [3.09e+04,6e+04]   [3.09e+04,6e+04]  
 [9] [3.09e+04,6e+04]   [3.09e+04,6e+04]   (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (1.1e+05,1.74e+05]
[13] (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (6e+04,1.1e+05]   
[17] (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (6e+04,1.1e+05]   
[21] (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (6e+04,1.1e+05]   
[25] (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (1.1e+05,1.74e+05]
[29] (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (1.1e+05,1.74e+05] (1.74e+05,2.4e+05] (6e+04,1.1e+05]   
[33] [3.09e+04,6e+04]   (1.1e+05,1.74e+05] (1.1e+05,1.74e+05] (6e+04,1.1e+05]   
[37] (1.1e+05,1.74e+05] (1.1e+05,1.74e+05] (1.1e+05,1.74e+05] (1.1e+05,1.74e+05]
[41] [3.09e+04,6e+04]   [3.09e+04,6e+04]   (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (1.1e+05,1.74e+05]
[45] (1.1e+05,1.74e+05] (1.1e+05,1.74e+05] (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (6e+04,1.1e+05]   
[49] (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (1.1e+05,1.74e+05] (1.1e+05,1.74e+05]
[53] (6e+04,1.1e+05]    (1.1e+05,1.74e+05] (1.74e+05,2.4e+05] [3.09e+04,6e+04]  
[57] [3.09e+04,6e+04]  
4 Levels: [3.09e+04,6e+04] (6e+04,1.1e+05] ... (1.74e+05,2.4e+05]
```

How can I get the maximum possible value in that ranges?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: why downvote? as akrun answer there is not a way to do it without a regular expression...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to extract the numeric values from the `levels` of the `cut` `factor` vector, convert to `numeric` and get the `min` and `max` from the vectors ('first' and 'last').

```
first <- as.numeric(sub("(\\(|\\[)([^,]+),.*", "\\2", levels(v1)))
last <- as.numeric(sub(".*,([^]]+)\\]", "\\1", levels(v1)))
min(first)
max(last)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("(1.1e+05,1.74e+05]", 
        "(6e+04,1.1e+05]", "[3.09e+04,6e+04]"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, with the regular expression I'm now able to retreive the boundaries of the ranges.